# Fast multi-tag search plus result ordering and paging?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, lucene.net, stack-overflow, tagging

Can somebody explain how StackOverflow search works? I would like to add same features to a project I'm working on.

In SO, it's possible to filter the questions by multiple tags (e.g. c#, java) and get results sorted/paged by date or number of votes?

I realize that RDBMS with full-text engine can be used to filter and sort the questions but I'm not sure if that's the best solution?

Is it possible to somehow get top N ordered results from a full-text index?

Maybe Lucene.NET or Redis or something similar is used?

Comment: RavenDB uses Lucene internally and offers paging, sorting etc. Also it stored your documents in a robust way, which Lucene isn't really suitable for. So you might want to take a look and see if it fits your needs, see http://ravendb.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As of April 2011, Stackoverflow uses Lucene.NET.

> Source: (Jeff Atwood) https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/

- Their old method was [Homebrew + Full Text SQL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19548/what-search-engine-stackoverflow-is-using)
- [How to search by tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438000/how-do-i-implement-tag-searching-with-lucene) in Lucene
- [`Top N` with Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Filter,%20int%29)
- [Paging with Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351176/paging-lucenes-search-results)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to implement efficient paging and custom ordering with Lucene?

Comment: Nope, sure don't -- but that would make a great stackoverflow question