# Lucene - How to get more doc

Tags: java, lucene

How can I get more doc in lucene4.Here is my code.

```
int limit = 1000;
TopFieldColletor collector = TopFieldColletor.create(sort,limit,true,false,false,false);
searcher.search(query,collector);
ScoreDoc[] sds = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
System.out.println("sd:" + sds.length);   
System.out.println("total:" + collector.getTotalHits());
```

This is my result:
sd:1000
total:9060
My question is I got the 1000 doc, how to get the next 1000, until the end to take.

Answer (score 0):

See this question for a direct answer to your question: [Paging Lucene's search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351176/paging-lucenes-search-results)

That said, I have yet to see a user who will try to look at 1000 search results. Most won't even look beyond the first 100.

So it's much more efficient to create search metadata that allow users to get to the desired result within the first 10 results (tops). That where Google spent most of the brainpower: Get the best results to the top.

If you want this for processing by a computer, then the answer is: Raise the limit. Ask for 10'000 documents per query. There is no way to tell Lucene to "continue" or resume a search.

Comment: Yes, they will not to look so many results.But current is an asynchronous query.Could I get the doc in query process.I would like to find such a way in lucene.

Comment: As I said, the current API only supports using a higher limit.